# using swagger (v3; yaml) multiparty form-data and node.js (backend) for file uploads

Tags: node.js, npm, swagger, multipartform-data, form-data

Question: why does this node.js upload file code work with jade but not when using swagger?

I have been trying to figure out how to upload a file using swagger (yaml), multiparty, form-data, and nodejs.

I found a nodejs code example on how to upload files from this website:
https://github.com/pillarjs/multiparty/blob/master/examples/azureblobstorage.js

Additionally, nodejs project(similar to nodejs codefound in the github link above) can also be found here (along with a sample project):

[description-of-demo](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/mihail_mateev/archive/2014/08/01/how-to-manage-microsoft-azure-blob-storage-with-node-js.aspx)
[outdated-but-nice-demo-app](https://github.com/ig-mmateev/Azure-Storage-NodeJS)

the nodejs code works as expected when the front end is jade. However the form.parser(req) seems fails when using swagger api. The reason seems to be because the data is located in a different location within the req. When successful, the data seems to be located in req._readableState.pipes. When using swagger, the data seems to be located in req.swagger.params.

I don't know if I am supposed to move the data into the req._readableState.pipes or if there is a different parser that should be used for swagger params (or something else is possibly messed up).

// swagger.yaml

```
  /azureFileTransfer:
    x-swagger-router-controller: azureFilesController
    post:
      operationId: uploadAzureFile
      description: upload azure file
      # ticket info to be stored : schema: $ref: "#/definitions/azureFileData"
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
        - name: azureFileDataParam
          description: the file to be uploaded
          in: formData
          required: false
          type: file
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/GeneralResponse"
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
```

// azureFilesController.js (nodejs code)

```
module.exports = { uploadAzureFile };
//POST 
function uploadAzureFile(req, res, next) {

  var multiparty = require('multiparty');

  var accessKey = '123456storagepassword';
  var storageAccount = 'myblobstorageName';
  var fs = require('fs');
  var container = 'containerwithinblobstorage';
  var blobService = azure.createBlobService(storageAccount, accessKey);
  var form = new multiparty.Form();

  form.on('part', function (part) {
    if (part.filename) {

      var size = part.byteCount - part.byteOffset;
      var name = part.filename;

      blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream(container, name, part, size, function (error) {
        if (error) {
          res.send(' Blob create: error ');
        }
      });
    } else {
      form.handlePart(part);
    }
  });
  form.parse(req); //req.swagger.params.file.value // req
  res.send('OK');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. It might not be the best way ... but it is A way to get a file up to azure blob storage. Using multer instead of multiparty. This is the bare basics without any (minimal) error checking or encryption. There is multer-azure and multer-azure-storage which i plan to look into as well [multer-azure](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-azure),
 [multer-azure-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-azure-storage)

// swagger.yaml (yaml ... backend))

```
  /azureFileTransfer:
x-swagger-router-controller: azureFilesController
post:
  operationId: uploadAzureFile
  description: upload azure file
  # ticket info to be stored : schema: $ref: "#/definitions/azureFileData"
  consumes:
    - multipart/form-data
  parameters:
    - name: azureFileDataParam
      description: the file to be uploaded
      in: formData
      required: false
      type: file
  responses:
    "200":
      description: Success
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/GeneralResponse"
    default:
      description: Error
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
```

// azureFilesController.js (nodejs-javascript code ... backend)

```
module.exports = { uploadAzureFile };

//POST 
function uploadAzureFile(req, res, next) {
  var azureStorage = require('azure-storage');
  var accessKey = 'keyfor_storageAccount';
  var storageAccount = 'azureBlobStorageName';
  var container = 'nameOfContainerInYourBlobStorage'; 
  var blobService = azureStorage.createBlobService(storageAccount, accessKey);

  var file_location = req.files[0].path;
  var file_name = req.files[0].originalname;
  blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile(container, file_name, file_location, function (error, result, response) {
    if (!error) {
      res.sendStatus(200); // file uploaded successfully
    }
    else {
      res.sendStatus(500);
    }
  });
}
```

// app.js (nodejs-javascript code ... backend)

```
var multer = require('multer');
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/' }).any());
```

// angularFile.js (angular-javascript code ... frontend)

```
$scope.uploadModel = function () {
  var file = $scope.myFile;
  console.log('file is ');
  console.dir(file);
  var base_uri = $scope.traSettingsService.baseUri;
  var uploadUrl = base_uri + 'azureFileTransfer/'; 
  uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
};

function uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl) {
  var testing = null;
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('file', file);
  $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.responseMessage = "Your file was successfully uploaded";
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    $scope.responseMessage = "The file failed to load. Please try again.";
  });
}
```